# I need to search from multiple table field of single table in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

```
$data = \app\models\Events::find()->
         where(['event_code''event_name'[] =>$_POST['event_code''event_name'] ])->all();

return $this->render('search',['data'=>$data]);
```

Here I need to search from both `event_code` and `event_name`. How can  I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `andWhere` to add multiple conditions

```
$data = \app\models\Events::find()->where(['=','event_code',$_POST['event_code']])->andWhere(['=','event_name',$_POST['event_name']])->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$data = \app\models\Events::find()->where(['event_code' => $_POST['event_code'], 'event_name' => $_POST['event_name']])->all();
```

Comment: @BibashAdhikari. POST doesn't contain `event_name`. What is `$_POST` values?